# How do I append user inputs to lists within class instance?

Tags: python

I am new to programming and am trying to create a program that will ask the user questions then store them in an instance to be used for matchmaking but I am having trouble being certain that the inputs are being properly stored. This is what I currently have.

```
ask_name = input("What is your name?  ")

print(f"Hello {ask_name}!")

class Member:
      
 """A place to store member interest info"""

       def __init__(self, book_list, movie_list, game_list):
              """Initialize book, movie, and game interest attributes"""
              self.book_list = book_list
              self.movie_list = movie_list
              self.game_list = game_list

member_0 = Member([''],[''],[''])

     

active = True

while active:
       
       books = input(f"What are your favorite books? Send one at a time. \n\t Send 'movies' when finished.  ")


       if books == 'movies':
              active = False
       else:
              answer = input(f" Is {books} one of your favorite books?\n\tSend 'yes' if it is. Send 'no' if it is not. ")
              if answer == 'yes':

                     print(f"{books} has been added to favorite books.")
                     member_0.book_list.append({books})
                     print(f"{member_0.book_list}")
              
                     




active = True

while active:
       

       movies = input(f"What are your favorite movies? Send one at a time.\n\tSend 'games' when finished.  ")

       if movies == 'games':
              active = False
       else:
              answer = input(f" Is {movies} one of your favorite movies?\n\tSend 'yes' if it is. Send 'no' if it is not. ")
              if answer == 'yes':
                     print(f"{movies} has been added to favorite movies.")
                     member_0.movie_list.append({movies})
                     print(f"{member_0.movie_list}")





active = True
while active:
       

       games = input(f"What are your favorite video games? Send one at a time.\n\tSend 'done' when finished.  ")

       if games == 'done':
              active = False
       else:
              answer = input(f" Is {games} one of your favorite games?\n\tSend 'yes' if it is. Send 'no' if it is not. ")
              if answer == 'yes':
                     print(f"{games} has been added to favorite video games.")
                     member_0.game_list.append({games})
                     print(f"{member_0.game_list}")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "properly"?

Comment: That they're being stored into the class instance attributes like I intended for them to

Comment: You're printing them out as you go.  What other kind of certainty do you need?

Comment: I wanted to print the three lists out together somehow to make sure that they were all in the same place, maybe that isn't necessary though. I'm going to revise my question though, because I think the real question is "How can I save those user inputs permanently?"

Comment: Before you update your question, try searching for your question and see if any of those results help. It'll likely be closed anyway -- not enough detail in its current form, and "how do I save permanently" definitely has duplicates -- unless you show your attempt at saving permanently and ask a _specific_ question.

Comment: Here are some helpful links: [tour], [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], 
the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), 
and [mre]. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Okay thank you all for your help. My bad for the unclear and duplicate question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest keeping your lists in a dictionary rather than as three different variables, and writing a function that will let you build any given list, so you don't have to copy+paste all of that code for each one:

```
class Member:
    """A place to store member interest info"""
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.favorites = {}

    def ask_favorites(self, things, done):
        if things not in self.favorites:
            self.favorites[things] = []
        while True:
            print(f"What are your favorite {things}?  Send one at a time.")
            thing = input(f"\tSend '{done}' when finished.  ")
            if thing == done:
                return
            print(f" Is {thing} one of your favorite {things}?")
            if input("\tSend 'yes' if it is.  Send 'no' if it is not. ") != 'yes':
                continue
            self.favorites[things].append(thing)
            print(f"{thing} has been added to favorite {things}.")
            print(self.favorites[things])

    def print_favorites(self):
        print(f"These are a few of {self.name}'s favorite things:")
        for things, faves in self.favorites.items():
            print(f"Favorite {things}: {', '.join(faves)}")

ask_name = input("What is your name?  ")
print(f"Hello {ask_name}!")

member_0 = Member(ask_name)
member_0.ask_favorites("books", "movies")
member_0.ask_favorites("movies", "games")
member_0.ask_favorites("games", "done")

member_0.print_favorites()
```